# Rubygems Chronic cannot parse "2010-09-12 3:12pm" but can parse "2010-09-12 3pm" or "last monday 3:12pm"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chronic

It seems strange that "2010--9-12 3:12pm" is a weak spot of Chronic Rubygem?  Is there a way to make it work?  (or another gem that can do it?)  I also hope to find a parser that can handle `2010-09-12 3:12pm UTC` or other timezones such as `PDT`, `PST`, or `UTC+8` or `-0700`

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"

irb(main):002:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require 'chronic'
=> true

irb(main):004:0> Chronic.parse('9/12/2010')
=> Sun Sep 12 12:00:00 -0700 2010

irb(main):005:0> Chronic.parse('9/12/2010 3pm')
=> Sun Sep 12 15:00:00 -0700 2010

irb(main):006:0> Chronic.parse('9/12/2010 3:12pm')    # <-- cannot work
=> nil

irb(main):007:0> Chronic.parse('last monday 3:12pm')
=> Mon Sep 06 15:12:00 -0700 2010

irb(main):008:0> Chronic.parse('2010-09-12')
=> Sun Sep 12 12:00:00 -0700 2010

irb(main):009:0> Chronic.parse('2010-09-12 3:12pm')   # <-- cannot work
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me using latest [`Chronic`](http://github.com/mojombo/chronic) on [Github](http://github.com) on Ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174):

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"

>> require './chronic/lib/chronic'
=> true

>> Chronic.parse('9/12/2010 3:12pm')
=> Sun Sep 12 15:12:00 +0100 2010

>> Chronic.parse('2010-09-12 3:12pm')
=> Sun Sep 12 15:12:00 +0100 2010
```

In the test suite there are tests for:

```
time = parse_now("2006-08-20 7pm")
assert_equal Time.local(2006, 8, 20, 19), time

time = parse_now("2006-08-20 03:00")
assert_equal Time.local(2006, 8, 20, 3), time
```

But not exact match to your problem date(s).  So if you have discovered a bug then it might be worth telling Chronic's author so that he can update the tests.

BTW... what do you get when you try:

```
require 'time'

puts Time.parse('2010-09-12 3:12pm')
```

Because I get the correct: `Sun Sep 12 15:12:00 +0100 2010` (NB. I'm in day light saving time here).  I mention this because I saw a ambiguous tweet this morning about *problem* with [time API in a minor point release](http://twitter.com/orangeacme/status/24365150845).

/I3az/

Comment: I couldn't use Time.parse because need the following format: (it treats the 12 as month) `Time.parse('09/12/2010 3:12pm PDT')` =>
`2010-12-09 14:12:00 -0800`

Comment: When I do `Time.parse('09/12/2010 3:12pm PDT')` I get `Sun Sep 12 23:12:00 +0100 2010` which is correctly converted time to my locale (GMT+1).  However I'm a bit surprised that it does MM/DD and not DD/MM in my locale!